# Can anyone tell me if there is a way to use lubuntu with a linux mint flavour/theme?

Tags: lubuntu, themes, icons, mint, icon-themes

I have tried before to use ubuntu with linux mint theme/icons...it worked pretty well. 
Is there a way to use linux mint themes/icons with lubuntu and enjoy its stability and speed?

Comment: What difficulty do you anticipate?

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, just install cinnamon. [Here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1246) you go !